# Calculate Android elevation to get Aspect 4:3

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview, aspect

[image]Hello i use  a card view with 6dp in elevation

but in my code when

```
height_4_3 = Functions.GetHeight4_3(parent.getWidth())


holder.parent_image.getLayoutParams().height = height_4_3;
holder.parent_image.requestLayout();
```

and i have a text view with 4:1 aspect

```
holder.parent_text_view.getLayoutParams().height = height_4_3 / 3
holder.parent_text_view.requestLayout();
```

i need subtracting the number elevation in aspect 4:3 and 4:1 that the elements are being put one over the other

**UPDATE**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent_card_view"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/parent_image"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/login_1"
                android:id="@+id/image_course"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/login_1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/parent_text_view">

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:textColor="@color/BLUE_HIGHT" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How is elevation related to the aspect ratio? All you need to do is set the height and width correctly, elevation has no effect on the aspect ratio.

Comment: when i have card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" the container  put one over the other, the parent_text_view put  over bottom parent_image

Comment: I have no idea what you are taking about. Can you show us an image or something that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Im update the quesiton with images and code